# For Wpf, is there an existing class to draw shapes in inkcanvas?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, canvas, inkcanvas

I'm looking for a class that allows the user to draw shapes via an inkcanvas. Similar to the microsoft products possible.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Please take a [tour][1] to learn How to ask a proper question.


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

Sure, [InkCanvas](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.inkcanvas?view=netframework-4.7.2) is now available for wpf. Take a look at [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/digital-ink).

```
digital ink is now available in the core Windows Presentation Foundation.
```